# Exponential Random Variables and Confidence

Tags: probability, random-variables, exponential-function

Assume that the amount of evidence against a defendant in a criminal trial is an exponential random variable
X. If the defendant is innocent, then X has mean 1, and if the defendant is guilty, then X has mean 2. The
defendant will be ruled guilty if X>c, where c is a suitably chosen constant. If the judge wants to be 95%
certain that an innocent man will not be convicted, what should the value of c be? Enter your answer as a
decimal and make sure that at least 8 digits after the decimal point are correct.

I'm a little confused on how to approach this. I think the constant C is really messing me up. Help please

Comment: Duplication.  Same question also asked here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/775102/exponential-random-variable-representation-of-criminal-trial

Answer (score 0):

You want to find $c$ such that $P(X < c) = 0.95$, where $X$ is an exponential random variable with mean $1$ (as it is if the defendant is an innocent man: it doesn't say what the judge would do if the defendant were a woman).